# Packages don't show up after adding ppa

Tags: software-center, software-sources

I added `ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/firefox-aurora/ubuntu oneiric` and `ppa:banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu oneiric` to my software sources, then did `apt-get update`. However, after selecting their specific sources from the menu in Software Center, the only packages available are language packs and extensions for Banshee and `firefox-aurora`. I had already uninstalled Banshee and Firefox.

If I try and install Banshee/Aurora with `sudo apt-get` it will install the old version. Searching for Banshee/Aurora in Software Center only shows the old version.

I'm guessing the packages in the PPAs conflict with the packages in the main sources. How do I install the newer versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, uninstall the packages you installed previously. At terminal type `sudo apt-get remove --purge banshee`, press ENTER key and do the same for the Firefox. Next type `sudo apt-get autoremove` ,to clear the system of any residing file.

To remove the PPA from repository copy and paste the following into your terminal `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/firefox-aurora/ubuntu oneiric  && ppa:banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu oneiric`.

As for the Firefox browser, you can download it from the official website if you are looking for the latest and follow instruction as prescribed on the site. Regarding Banshee, the truth is that Banshee will only allow you the repository for the stable release, though,you would be allowed to download the latest release for Ubuntu that will always return you back to the stable release.